# jquery remove focus issue with twitter-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, focus, tooltip

I have a test page with bootstrap 3 using [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) to display a message to the user when the user mouses over an icon.

Clicking on the icon displays a [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and when the modal is closed, the tooltip remains displayed to the user because the focus is still applied to the icon.

The only way to remove the displayed tootip is when the user physically clicks somewhere on the form to remove the focus from the icon.

I have noticed that the display of the tooltip issue occurs on the [tooltip examples page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples).

I have tried to use jquery to remove the focus when the user clicks on the icon, but this approach did not work as anticipated.

Here is my html code:

```
<a href="" id="id_page_help" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" rel="tooltip" class="no_decoration" title="Help">
    <i class="icon-bulb icon_size18"></i>
</a>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
    $('#id_page_help').click(function () {
        $('#id_page_help').blur();
        //alert('xxxx'); //alert does display - code triggered.
    });
</script>
```

**I am hoping that someone can point out what I have done incorrectly or supply a way to remove the focus.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Just use focus event instead of click event... this should help

    $('#id_page_help').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).blur()
    })
```

Comment: Chetan, this will work for all the links - not just the modal links in my test page.

Comment: This has specific id right?  it will apply only to the link you specify. You are anyways improve the selector to match your context. Or am i missing anything?

Comment: A huge problem using this code is the input elements with tool-tip attached will become un-clickable as the this code will blur as we click(focus) on it.
Use 
`$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.trigger = 'hover';`
before initializing tooltip to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but for anyone having the same issue,
this can also be done by overriding the default 'trigger' for tooltips:

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.trigger = 'hover';   // Set the default trigger to hover
```

This will show all tooltips only when hovering over the target element as oposed to the default behaviour which is to trigger the tooltip on hover and focus on the target element.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is really an issue in *twitter bootstrap*.

And in your case you've to use *modal-box events* and *jQuery*'s `blur` for handiling `:focus` for the `button`.

Here's the `jQuery` I've used:

```
 /*  #tooltip is id for button
     #myModal is id for modal-box */
 $('#tooltip').tooltip();

 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#tooltip').blur(); /* To hide the tooltip on modal-box show */
 });

 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
       console.log(e);
       $('#tooltip').tooltip('blur'); /* To hide the tooltip on modal-box close*/
 });
```

I've also created a [*JSFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/b5tgjvhu/10).

Please have a look, that will do the trick for you.

Comment: vivekkupadhyay, thanks - this was helpful, but chetans answer will work for all links, not just the modal links.

Comment: As it was not specified in your que and you're concerned for modal-box that's why, nevertheless, whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script in `$(document).ready(function() {....});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).tooltip({ show: false, hide: false }).click( function () {
          $(this).tooltip("close");
    }); // your tooltip script 

    $('div').on("click", "#id_page_help", function() {
        $(this).blur();
       //alert('xxxx'); //alert does display - code triggered.
        return;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

try the below code instead of the above code

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').hover(function(){$(this).tooltip('show')});
```